# Google Maps (JavaScript API) and Tablet Touch Events

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-maps

I use the following code (I quote parts of it) to post markers on a google map by right click to a point.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {
// code for open bubble for new marker
            });
```

I need to open the bubble, also when someone do a long press tap on his tablet. Basically I need to make the application usable also for tablet/mobile users.

I read about jQuery plugins that handle touch events, but I don't know how to use them. I need a simple solution based on the code above (to run the "//code" which open the bubble.

Comment: Should consider sharing back what other methods you found to slove this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the tabHold function on jQuery, with the click [event in Google Maps JS API v2](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/map_events/map_events.html).

[The taphold function](https://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/) in jQuery, can get the tab and hold action on tablet. But it does not return a lat lng to us.

For lat lng, we can grab it from the [Google Maps Onclick function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events).

So we can combine the two like the following:
1. let `tabhold` set a flag, to indicate that this click function is from tabhold
2. on the onclick function, check if this current click event is from tabhold, if so, perform the action.

I have a quick [demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nf9nbcfo/1/), I just copied and pasted some code so it looks kind of ugly. But hopefully it helps.